# Linux command line software to query cryptocurrencies prices

Tags: gratis, web-services, finance, cryptocurrency

I need a command line program or API library in python to query prices in EUR, volume, difficulty, hashrate of most important cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin, Ripple, Litecoin, etc for implement it in a Web page that I'm programming. I need that it be free.